# Why do background images and absolute position to 50% behave differently?

Tags: css

Image background position to 50% left center the background image but 50% left in absolute positioned element doesn't center the div element why?

Here is the code:

```
<div style="position:relative;height:100px; background:url(images/demo.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0">
   <div style="min-height:40px; width:140px; background-color:#aaa;position:absolute;top:0;left:50%;">
        heloo this is just a demo
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative positioning as declared in the `background-position` property takes into account the dimensions of the image being positioned, whereas when using a CSS positional property (`top,right,bottom,left`) only take the relative parent's dimensions into account.

A good way to think about it is using the minimum and maximum values:

1. With 0%, the effect is identical:

   - background-positioned image hugs the left edge of the containing element
   - absolutely positioned element hugs the left edge of the relative parent
2. With 100%, the effect is clearly different:

   - background-positioned image hugs the right edge of the containing element
   - absolutely positioned element's left edge lines up with relative parent's right edge

To solve your problem, you can add a negative margin of half the element's width to the second div:

```
margin-left: -70px;
```

Answer (score 0):

The left side of the child `div` will be halfway across the parent `div` with `left: 50%;`. To center the child `div` use `left: 50%;` and `margin-left: -(half the width of child div)`

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple, I would suggest simply removing `position:absolute;top:0;left:50%;` and using `margin: 0 auto;` instead.